# Django Image Upload, "no such column..."

Tags: python, django

The models were uploaded cleanly to the database and everything shows up properly on the admin page. When I attempted to upload an image it looked like it work. The admin page went back to the index of "products", but when I click on the product name to view its information and images I get this error:

```
"no such column: polls_image.product_image_id"
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

class Image(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/')
```

admin.py

```
class InlineImage(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineImage]
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/'
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

I am currently in the learning phase and just want the files to upload to the root of the project for simplicity.

Comment: I don't see a `product_image_id` attribute anywhere in this code.

Comment: Does your database table `polls_image` actually have a column named `product_image_id`? If you used `syncdb` to create your tables, django should've named the column in that manner.  If you created the DB manually, you may have missed that.  Django appends `_id` to ForeignKey column names.

Comment: I used syncdb, but yes that's the confusing part for me. I never created product_image_id and I never asked for it to be created. So, i'm guessing syncdb didn't do its job properly for some reason.

Comment: As Danos2000 said: your model field product_image will be created as product_image_id. That is a django convention. What does your table structure look like? Is product_image_id actually there? You didn't answer this question by Danos2000 so far. Btw: you should name this column simply product as it is a relation TO a product and not a relation to a product image.

Comment: No, it was not there, I've been messing around with my models a lot and running syncdb many times. I'm guess it just got a little confused along the way because I just deleted my db, resynced it, and it got rid of the problem.